# Getting Invalid version: "1.0" when running sfdx force:project:create

Tags: salesforcedx

When I am running following SFDX command sfdx force:project:create --projectname mywork getting the following error Invalid version: "1.0"

No other SFDX command gives me this error. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you creating the project in an existing project directory? I suspect that might be the problem.

Comment: No I am creating outside an existing sfdx project.

Comment: Can you tell us more about: your project structure, and share the way you're using the command (parameters, etc.). I'm pretty sure attempting to make your project folder outside of a SFDX project will fail as `force:source:push` and other metadata commands require there to be a DX-based source folder, and that needs to be in a dx project.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  If so please share it as I'm currently having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but its never been answered and I wanted to help others who may find themselves here like I did.  I posted this issue on the sfdx github project and received a solution:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/775#issuecomment-754181203

To quote the solution:

> In the current working directory where you are running the project
> create command, does somewhere up the path exist a package.json file
> with the version property specified as "version": "1"?
>
> For example:
>
> Running force:project:create in this directory:
> /Users/xxx/Desktop/sfdx/
>
> When a package.json file exists here: /Users/xxx/package.json
>
> and in that file is "version": "1", which is an invalid semver
> pattern.
>
> There is a weird behavior of the yeoman-generator module that powers
> the template create commands where it traverses up the current working
> directory and validates some package.json file it finds. You can
> either delete this file or set the version to a valid semver number.

I hope this helps somebody!